# How to update a dictionary value in an array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I hate to ask this, as I feel I'm missing something super simple, but I've been banging my head on this issue, way too long.

When a user taps on a cell in my `collectionView` I store the indexPath.row and a value called `timeOnIce` in an array called `tappedArray`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! BenchCollectionViewCell

     if cell.cellBackgroundImageView.image == UIImage(named: "collectionviewcell_60x60_white") {

        cell.cellBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "collectionviewcell_60x60_blue")

        let currentPlayerSelected = ["indexPath": indexPath.row, "timeOnIce": 0]
        tappedArray.append(currentPlayerSelected)

     } else {

       cell.cellBackgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "collectionviewcell_60x60_white")

       tappedArray = tappedArray.filter { $0["indexPath"] != indexPath.row }

     }
}
```

A button to start a timer is pressed

```
func startTimer()  {

    //start the timer
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateCounters), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}  //startTimer
```

If two players are tapped (added to `tappedArray`) the array looks like the following:

```
tappedArray [["timeOnIce": 0, "indexPath": 1], ["timeOnIce": 0, "indexPath": 0]]
```

I'm having the hardest time trying to figure out how to update the `timeOnIce` in the dictionary to include the `timerCounter`

```
@objc func updateCounters() {

    timerCounter += 1

    for row in tappedArray {

        print("row \(row)")

    }

    //Update tableview
    tableView.reloadData()

}  //updateCounters
```

This is what row prints out

```
row ["timeOnIce": 0, "indexPath": 2]
row ["timeOnIce": 0, "indexPath": 1]
row ["timeOnIce": 0, "indexPath": 0]
```

If I try the following in the for..in loop

```
row["timeOnIce"] = timerCounter
```

I get the following error

```
`Cannot assign through subscript: 'row' is a 'let' constant`
```

unless I change loop to the following:

```
for var row in tappedArray {

   print("row \(row)")

   row["timeOnIce"] = timerCounter

}
```

But the value doesn't get updated in the array...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Dictionary` is a value type in Swift, the `for` loop makes a copy of the items in the array.  To update the original, you can use an index into the array like this:

```
for row in tappedArray.indices {

   print("row \(tappedArray[row])")

   tappedArray[row]["timeOnIce"] = timerCounter
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dict1 = [String: Any]()
dict1.updateValue("Vanilla", forKey: "Ice Cream")

var dict2 = [String: Any]()
dict2.updateValue("World", forKey: "Hello")

var arr = [[String:Any]]()
arr.append(dict1)
arr.append(dict2)

print("arr-original: ", arr)

for (index, _) in arr.enumerated() {
    
    if arr[index].contains(where: { $0.key == "Hello" }) {
        arr[index]["Hello"] = "Dude"
    }
}

print("arr-updated: ", arr)
```